# disable scrolling for mobile on click

Tags: jquery

This code disables scrolling for mobile device, is it possible that it only works when i click on `.navicon` ?

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

menu nav icon

```
    <a href="#"class="show-menu navicon">Main Menu</a>
```

to something like this ?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.navicon').toggle(function () {
            $("html").bind('touchmove', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }, function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So my solution for this problem was folowing

```
$('.navicon').toggle(function () {
    $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });  
},function () {
    $(document).unbind('touchmove');  
});
```